# How to template prestashop module admin section with smarty

Tags: module, smarty, prestashop

I want to build a module where , we like to build the form and table using smarty.

In prestashop module controller load template file like
/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/my_module.tpl

where admin will be /modules/my_module/views/templates/admin/admin_module.tpl

My point is how can i show this admin_module.tpl in the prestashop module configuration page.

Answer (score 7):

It is really easy. You just have to create `views/templates/admin/foo.tpl` and then only display your template in `getContent()` method:

```
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/foo.tpl');
}
```